# Handling very large data with mysql

Tags: mysql, database, performance, indexing, partitioning

Sorry for the long post!

I have a database containing ~30 tables (InnoDB engine). Only two of these tables, namely, "transaction" and "shift" are quite large (the first one have 1.5 million rows and shift has 23k rows). Now everything works fine and I don't have problem with the current database size.

However, we will have a similar database (same datatypes, design ,..) but much larger, e.g., the "transaction" table will have about **1 billion records** (about 2,3 million transaction per day) and we are thinking about how we should deal with such volume of data in MySQL? (it is both read and write intensive). I read a lot of related posts to see if Mysql (and more specifically InnoDB engine) can perform well with billions of records, but still I have some questions. Some of those related posts that I've read are in the following:

- [Can MySQL reasonably perform queries on billions of rows?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20335/can-mysql-reasonably-perform-queries-on-billions-of-rows)
- [Is InnoDB (MySQL 5.5.8) the right choice for multi-billion rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121905/is-innodb-mysql-5-5-8-the-right-choice-for-multi-billion-rows)
- [Best data store for billions of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794736/best-data-store-for-billions-of-rows?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How big can a MySQL database get before performance starts to degrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276/how-big-can-a-mysql-database-get-before-performance-starts-to-degrade)
- [Why MySQL could be slow with large tables?](https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/06/09/why-mysql-could-be-slow-with-large-tables/)
- [Can Mysql handle tables which will hold about 300 million records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733462/can-mysql-handle-tables-which-will-hold-about-300-million-records?noredirect=1&lq=1)

What I've understood so far to improve the performance for very large tables:

1. (for innoDB tables which is my case) increasing the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` (e.g., up to 80% of RAM).
   Also, I found some other MySQL performance tunning settings [here in
   percona blog](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/28/10-mysql-performance-tuning-settings-after-installation/)
2. having proper indexes on the table (using EXPLAN on queries)
3. partitioning the table
4. MySQL Sharding or clustering

Here are my questions/confusions:

- About partitioning, I have some doubts whether we should use it or not. On one hand many people suggested it to improve performance when table is very large. On the other hand, I've read many posts saying it does not improve query performance and it does not make queries run faster (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249073/partitioning-for-query-performance-in-sql-server-2008/4249447#4249447) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141175/partitioning-a-large-table-has-not-improved-performance-why)). Also, I read in [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-limitations-storage-engines.html) that **InnoDB foreign keys and MySQL partitioning are not compatible** (we have foreign keys).
- Regarding indexes, right now they perform well, but as far as I understood, for very large tables indexing is more restrictive (as Kevin Bedell mentioned in his answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20335/can-mysql-reasonably-perform-queries-on-billions-of-rows)). Also, indexes speed up reads while slow down write (insert/update). So, for the new similar project that we will have this large DB, should we first insert/load all the data and then create indexes? (to speed up the insert)
- If we cannot use partitioning for our big table ("transaction" table), what is an alternative option to improve the performance? (except MySQl variable settings such as `innodb_buffer_pool_size`). Should we use Mysql clusters? (we have also lots of joins)

## EDIT

This is the `show create table` statement for our largest table named "transaction":

```
  CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `terminal_transaction_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `fuel_terminal_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `fuel_terminal_serial` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `xboard_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `gas_station_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `operator_id` text NOT NULL,
 `shift_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `xboard_total_counter` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `fuel_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `start_fuel_time` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `end_fuel_time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `preset_amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `actual_amount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fuel_cost` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `payment_cost` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `purchase_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `payment_ref_id` text,
 `unit_fuel_price` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `fuel_status_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fuel_mode_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `payment_result` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `card_pan` text,
 `state` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `totalizer` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `shift_start_time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `terminal_transaction_id` (`terminal_transaction_id`,`fuel_terminal_id`,`start_fuel_time`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `start_fuel_time_idx` (`start_fuel_time`),
 KEY `fuel_terminal_idx` (`fuel_terminal_id`),
 KEY `xboard_idx` (`xboard_id`),
 KEY `gas_station_id` (`gas_station_id`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `purchase_type` (`purchase_type`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `shift_start_time` (`shift_start_time`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `fuel_type` (`fuel_type`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1665335 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 77, accepted):

- Can MySQL reasonably perform queries on billions of rows? -- MySQL can 'handle' billions of rows.  "Reasonably" depends on the queries; let's see them.
- Is InnoDB (MySQL 5.5.8) the right choice for multi-billion rows? -- 5.7 has some improvements, but 5.5 is pretty good, in spite of being <strike>nearly 6</strike> 8 years old, and <strike>on the verge of</strike> no longer being supported.
- Best data store for billions of rows -- If you mean 'Engine', then InnoDB.
- How big can a MySQL database get before the performance starts to degrade -- Again, that depends on the queries.  I can show you a 1K row table that will meltdown; I have worked with billion-row tables that hum along.
- Why MySQL could be slow with large tables? -- range scans lead to I/O, which is the slow part.
- Can Mysql handle tables which will hold about 300 million records? -- again, yes.  The limit is somewhere around a trillion rows.
- (for InnoDB tables which is my case) increasing the innodb_buffer_pool_size (e.g., up to 80% of RAM). Also, I found some other MySQL performance tunning settings here in Percona blog -- yes
- having proper indexes on the table (using EXPLAIN on queries) -- well, let's see them.  There are a lot of mistakes that can be made in this *critical* area.
- partitioning the table -- "Partitioning is not a panacea!"  I harp on that in [*my blog*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/partition-maintenance/)
- MySQL Sharding -- Currently this is DIY
- MySQL clustering -- Currently the best answer is some Galera-based option (PXC, MariaDB 10, DIY w/Oracle). Oracle's "Group Replication" ("InnoDB Cluster") is a viable contender.
- Partitioning does not support `FOREIGN KEY` or "global" `UNIQUE`.
- UUIDs, at the scale you are talking about, will not just slow down the system, but actually kill it.  [*Type 1 UUIDs*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/guiduuid-performance/) may be a workaround.
- Insert and index-build speed -- There are too many variations to give a single answer.  Let's see your tentative `CREATE TABLE` and how you intend to feed the data in.
- Lots of joins -- "Normalize, but don't over-normalize."  In particular, do not normalize datetimes or floats or other "continuous" values.
- Do build [*summary tables*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-warehousing-summary-tables/)
- 2,3 million transactions per day -- If that is 2.3M *inserts* (30/sec), then there is not much of a performance problem.  If more complex, then RAID, SSD, batching, etc, may be necessary.
- deal with such volume of data -- If most activity is with the "recent" rows, then the buffer_pool will nicely 'cache' the activity, thereby avoiding I/O.  If the activity is "random", then MySQL (or *anyone* else) will have I/O issues.
- Shrinking the datatypes helps in a table like yours.  I doubt if you need 4 bytes to specify `fuel_type`.  There are multiple 1-byte approaches.

Comment: One more item -- "MySQL NDB Cluster" is different than Galera; NDB has a niche market; it _might_ be useful to you; let's see more about your app.

Comment: Thanks Rick for the detailed answer. Now my main concern is that I am not sure whether we should do clustering or not (I've never done it before). I mean when should we do it and when we should not? what factors should I consider before clustering? and if we have to do it, where should I start from?

Comment: Also, you said you should see the queries (for indexing, performance, ..). What info about queries should I consider? what info about our app do you need? How could I show the queries to you ? (sorry if it is stupid question!)

Comment: Type of data -- money transfers?  logging?  data warehousing?  scientific research readings?

Comment: Tables and queries - output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, text of `SELECT` and `UPDATE` statements (even if tentative).  Those will show (1) what indexes you currently have, and (2) what indexes you need.

Comment: Is the data 'purged' periodically?  (A time-series might be keeping data for 30 days, then deleting old stuff.)  This can lead to tips on how to significantly speed up that process.

Comment: "Reports" - Do you have daily summary reports involving `GROUP BY`?  More tips available.

Comment: Thanks Rick for your help. I added the `show create table` to my question. This is a web application related to oil transactions of some fuel stations in my city.

Comment: What I really don't know is should we always use partitioning or clustering when the database is so large?

Comment: Size does _not_ indicate a necessity for partitioning.  Write activity _does_ indicate a need for _sharding_.  HA (High Availbility) is one indicator for "clustering".  More than 100 rows inserted/updated per second indicates _some_ action, but usually you can get to 1000/sec without sharding/clustering/etc.  Massive "reports" involving "group by" indicates "Summary tables".  Etc.

Answer (score 4):

When collecting billions of rows, it is better (when possible) to consolidate, process, summarize, whatever, the data *before* storing.  Keep the raw data in a file if you think you need to get back to it.

Doing that will eliminate most of your questions and concerns, plus speed up the processing.

Comment: I concur. It's basically doing the same amount of processing, but spread out over time instead of at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Crossed 2.7 BL data with a real time VTS system without a trouble. Special case is that the database not only stores data, but real time read availability is a crucial part too, otherwise real time tracking purpose is not met. Following things helped in the first place;

1. Handsome normalization;
2. Serious indexing;
3. InnoDB;
4. Calculated columns as cache;
5. Query optimization;
6. It survives (so far) with x4 cores & x8 GB RAM on an SSD (VPS)
7. Summary tables for reporting & backlog;