# Please suggest a NoSql datastore for my requirement

Tags: sql-server, database, nosql

Currently i'm storing two day's data(200M rows with 5 columns in each) in an RDBMS (mssql)- yesterday's and today's tables, so i keep removing older tables which are no longer useful. I always read and update data in yesterday's table and insert data in today's table.

Whenever i read some rows from yesterday's table, i increment a status column in the table for those rows by 1, so that i'd read those rows again only after i've read all the other rows which match the criteria (some criteria based on other columns).
I want to move to a noSql db for my use case. Please suggest which ones might be worth looking at.

Comment: i  thought nosql was a magic bullet for big rows,but this answer helped me ,check this out :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794736/best-data-store-for-billions-of-rows/2794983#2794983

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very clear why you would want to move to a NoSQL database - I am not suggesting you shouldn't.

You could take a look at Oracle NoSQL Database, it will allow you to map your current model to its Table API, also supports Time-to-live that purges data based on elapsed time (It is not clear if you purge tables only after some time window is elapsed). It supports JSON Document, and Key-Value API as well.